# Python Pip Installing for Wrong Version

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I know this question has been asked before, but my issue is a bit different. I have both pip2.7 installed and working and pip3.4 installed and working (with my Python 2.7 and 3.4 versions), but my pip2.7 is installing in the wrong directory (it is installing in the 3.4 folder).

[image]

As you can see, I have both versions working, and from everything else I've read online these should point to my two different versions of Python, yet they are pointing to the same directory. I can't find anything about manually changing where pip2.7 is pointing. Thanks!

Comment: is `PYTHONPATH` set?

Comment: @cel I have my Python directory in my PATH variable. Does that effectively do the same thing or do I need to add a separate variable as PYTHONPATH? I can run python2.7 and python from my command line and both run.

Comment: The best way to avoid this kind of problem is to use virtualenv http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: @JennerFelton, no there's a specific environment variable named `PYTHONPATH`. It's important for your question to know, if this variable is set. And if so, what value it has.

Comment: I suggest uninstalling both versions and then using conda  to install them into different environments

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest to uninstall and reinstall `pip`. Do so by running

```
pip uninstall pip
```

Download the `get-pip.py` bootstrapper from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and run

```
python2.7 get-pip.py
```

or

```
python3.4 get-pip.py
```

respectively.

Comment: And I installed pip with python3 and it STILL installed packaged under python2.7

Comment: Hey @dave-appleton, is there a pip3 command available? If so, you could either use it right away or, for convenience, redirect the pip symlink to this binary (assuming you use some UNIX derivate).