# ImportError: No module named plyfile

Tags: python-2.7

I have installed plyfile using the pip install. Then I executed the following snipper inside a file named "testview.py":

```
# Python imports
import sys, os


## Imports from this project
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'core')) 
# hack to allow local imports without creaing a module or modifying the path variable

from InputOutput import *
from MeshDisplay import MeshDisplay
from HalfEdgeMesh import *


def main():

    # Get the path for the mesh to load, either from the program argument if
    # one was given, or a dialog otherwise
    if(len(sys.argv) > 1):
        filename = sys.argv[1]
else:
    print("ERROR: No file name specified. Proper syntax is 'python testview.py path/to/your/mesh.obj'.")
    exit()

# Read in the mesh
mesh = HalfEdgeMesh(readMesh(filename))

# Create a viewer window
winName = 'meshview -- ' + os.path.basename(filename)
meshDisplay = MeshDisplay(windowTitle=winName)
meshDisplay.setMesh(mesh)
meshDisplay.startMainLoop()


if __name__ == "__main__": main()
```

with the following command:

```
python testview.py ../meshes/bunny.obj



Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "testview.py", line 13, in <module>
from InputOutput import *
   File "../core/InputOutput.py", line 2, in <module>
from plyfile import PlyData, PlyElement, make2d
ImportError: No module named plyfile
```

How to check that plyfile is indeed installed. I have installed it with the following command:

```
sudo -H pip install plyfile
```

And I got the following output of the above command:

```
Requirement already satisfied: plyfile in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.8 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from plyfile)
```

By the way I have both python 2.7 and python 3+ installed on ubuntu. Some hint to get around this issue?

Comment: what is your system default python `python -V` output? It looks like you're using python3 syntax but running the script with python2.

Comment: with python -V I got Python 2.7.13

Comment: Ah, ok, looks like `plyfile` got installed for python3. Try running your script with python3: `python3 testview.py ../meshes/bunny.obj`

Comment: The codebase is strictly for python 2.7. Is it possible to force to reinstall plyfile with pip only for python 2.7 ?

Comment: of course, `pip3 install plyfile` or `python3 -m pip install plyfile` (`sudo` if necessary)

Comment: I can only guess that downshift meant `python -m pip install plyfile` (i.e. no 3). Also, you might use `python -m pip install --user plyfile` to avoid touching the Python install.

Comment: @Pierre I did mean `python3`: [How to make 'python' program command execute Python 3?](https://askubuntu.com/q/320996)

Comment: I understood that @sajis997 wanted to remain on Python 2. Can you clarify @sajis997? Of course it if intriguing that `sudo -H pip install plyfile` returns import errors from python3 install trees.

Comment: @Pierre yes, i agree, indeed you are correct! my mistake for misreading..

Comment: @sajis997, you may want to try reinstalling `pip` as suggested in this answer [Python Pip Installing for Wrong Version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32817111/1248974)