# matplotlib installing for python 3.7 not 3.7.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, matplotlib, pip

I installed `python3` on Windows using the Anaconda installer. I then installed `matplotlib` using `pip`.

However, I can't get matplotlib to work in Sublime Text. When I try import `matplotlib.pyplot as plt` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.pyplot'; 'matplotlib' is not a package`.

If I run python in the console it works fine.

It turns out I have two versions of python installed.

```
pip 20.1.1 from c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.7)
```

```
python --version
Python 3.7.6
```

I saw that I can install for a specific version of python here: [Python Pip Installing for Wrong Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32474011/python-pip-installing-for-wrong-version)

However none of `py -3.7.6 -m pip install matplotlib`, `python-3.7.6 -m pip install matplotlib`, `python3.7.6 -m pip install matplotlib` work and if I explicitly run pip with python 3.7.6 via `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe -m pip install matplotlib` it says already installed and I still get the same error.

**How do I get `matplotlib` installed for python 3.7.6 so I can use it in Sublime Text?**

Answer (score 0):

Use this command :

```
python3.7 -m pip install matplotlib
```

You're not supposed to run `python3.7.6` since you can have only one of the 3.7 versions installed.

Hope this works for you!

Comment: Huh? I'm not following. I thought the issue is because I do have two 3.7 versions installed.

Comment: 'python3.7' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: You're using anoconda, I'm not familiar with it, make sure to check on how to use it.